# Scrollbar not showing in application | Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to make a console in which it has two widgets:

1. A text input widget that takes in user inputs
2. A readonly text input widget that shows responses and user inputs

I have the following code below:

**structure.kv:**

```
<Structure>
    AnchorLayout:
        size: root.layout_top_width, root.layout_top_height
        anchor_y: "top"

        ScrollView:
            scroll_type: ['bars', 'content']

        TextInput:
            text: "1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n"
            size_hint_y: root.text_input_top_height
            font_name: root.text_font
            background_color: "black"
            foreground_color: "white"
            multiline: True
            readonly: True

    AnchorLayout:
        size: root.layout_bottom_width, root.layout_bottom_height
        anchor_y: "bottom"

        TextInput:
            background_color: "#1a1a1a"
            font_name: root.text_font
            foreground_color: "white"
            multiline: False
```

**structure.py:**

```py
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
import os


class Structure(Widget):
    """Widget Layout Class

    Class that houses all of the widgets for the console window
    """
    # Class variables
    layout_top_width = ObjectProperty(int)
    layout_top_height = ObjectProperty(int)
    layout_bottom_width = ObjectProperty(int)
    layout_bottom_height = ObjectProperty(int)
    text_input_top_height = ObjectProperty(int)
    text_font = ObjectProperty(str)

    def __init__(self, width, height, **kwargs):
        """Constructor for Structure class

        Constructs an instance of the structure class
        :param width: [INTEGER], width specification of the console window
        :param height: [INTEGER], height specification of the console window
        """
        # Intakes values from parameters to instance variables
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

        # Calculates layout dimension specifications and defines other properties
        Structure.layout_bottom_width = self.width
        Structure.layout_bottom_height = 27
        Structure.layout_top_width = self.width
        Structure.layout_top_height = self.height
        Structure.text_input_top_height = (self.height - 27) / self.height
        Structure.text_font = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + "/asset/Consolas.ttf"

        # Calls widget constructor
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

**console.py:**

```py
from YUCLI.structure import Structure
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
import os

# Loads design profile
root = Builder.load_file(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '/structure.kv')


class Console(App):
    """Console Class

    Main class that houses all functions and features for the customizable console
    """

    def __init__(self, title, width, height, **kwargs):
        """Constructor for console class

        Constructs an instance of the Console class

        :param title: [STRING], title of the console window
        :param width: [INTEGER], resizes console to specified width
        :param height: [INTEGER], resizes console to specified height
        """
        # Intakes values from parameters to instance variables
        self.title = title
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

        # Calls app constructor
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        """Window Constructor Method

        Constructors window with specified properties
        :return Structure: [Structure] Class that houses widgets for console window
        """
        # Constructs console window
        Window.size = (self.width, self.height)
        Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', False)
        Config.write()

        # Returns structure class
        return Structure(self.width, self.height)

    def test_variables__(self):
        """Variable Printer Method [PRIVATE]

        Prints all instance variables held within this class
        Not meant for outside access
        Remove upon publishing
        """
        # Prints current instance variables
        print("self.title: " + str(self.title))
        print("self.width: " + str(self.width))
        print("self.height: " + str(self.height))
```

The issue that I'm facing is that the readonly text input widget scrolls long text, but the scrollbar isn't appearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the way to do this.

```
<Structure>

    AnchorLayout:
        size: root.layout_top_width, root.layout_top_height
        anchor_y: "top"

        ScrollView:
            id: scroll
            size_hint: (1, root.text_input_top_height)
            scroll_type: ['bars']
            bar_width: 13

            TextInput:
                text: root.text_history
                font_name: root.text_font
                background_color: "black"
                foreground_color: "white"
                readonly: True
                height: max(self.minimum_height, scroll.height)
                size_hint: 1, None

    AnchorLayout:
        size: root.layout_bottom_width, root.layout_bottom_height
        anchor_y: "bottom"

        TextInput:
            background_color: "#1a1a1a"
            font_name: root.text_font
            foreground_color: "white"
            multiline: False
```